# Symfony how read CSV file inside of entity class

Tags: php, symfony, csv

I am using Symfony2 and I am trying to come up with the best scenario possible for uploading a file and validating its contents before creating a record in the db.

I can upload the file with no issues.

Where I am running into the issues is here. I want to validate that the csv file contains the correct number of fields and that the data in the fields is accurate before actually creating the entry in the db table. (I understand I will have to create additional functions to actually check the data in the fields)

Is this best done in the entity class in my upload() function?

Here is my Import entity class:

```
 /**
 * Upload an import file
 */
public function upload(){
    // File prop can be empty
    if(NULL === $this->getFile()){
        return;
    }

    $fileName = $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName();

    // Move file to target directory using org. name
    $this->getFile()->move($this->getUploadAbsolutePath(), $fileName);
```

Can I check the csv's contents here?

How do I read that file from right here inside this entity function?

I've tried this and it doesn't work...

```
 $readFile = $this->getUploadAbsolutePath() . $fileName;
 $readFile->getData()->openFile('r');
```

If the file checks out and all is well then I can put an if statement around the following values? Anyone have any suggestions?

```
    // set the path field
    $this->setPath($this->getUploadPath() . $fileName);

    // set the import file field value
    $this->setImportFile($fileName);

    // set the batchId value
    $this->setBatchId($this->getRandomCode());

    // set the file value
    $this->setFile();

}
```